# How to execute OCaml code from Scala/Java?

Tags: java, scala, compiler-construction, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm about to write an abstract syntax for OCaml in scala, in combination with a pretty printer.
After that I want execute the generated OCaml code from scala and work with the result.

Is there a way to do that, without running a external OCaml compiler, execute the program and reading the result from stdout?

Comment: You'd have to write your own OCaml compiler, at least good enough to handle your own code. And then presumably test it for compatibility with the standard compiler, maintain it, etc. So, better to just run the usual compiler instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call external processes from Scala, take a look on the built-in [processes DSL](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package). It's pretty nice.

You can also fall back to the simple Java solutions (i.e., `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec()`).

Answer (score 1):

Preview version of OCaml-Java is available. http://ocamljava.x9c.fr/preview/#scripting